# How to stop "Just In Time Debugging" messages blocking a buildserver

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

Our buildserver (TeamCity, much recommended), runs our a whole bunch of testsuites on our finished c++ program.

Once in a whole, a test causes our program to crash, often bringing up a VisualStudio dialog offering me to JustInTime debug the crash.  The dialog stops the buildserver from progressing. Instead of the build marked as failed, it just hangs.  I've turned off the Just In Time debugging feature in VisualStudio, but when it's turned off, you still get a message "Couldn't JustinTime Debug this, you can turn it on in the options".

Does anybody know of a way to ensure that any unhandled exception in a program does not result in any modal dialog?

Comment: since the majority of our developers work in hand holding visual studio land, our build/test server runs under linux to verify that their changes work on "that other platform". our test apps are all console with custom debug break handlers it does sound unusual to run tests with the debugger attached as i believe you're describing...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[This MSDN article explains how to disable Just-In-Time debugging on a Windows server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6%28VS.80%29.aspx).  I've included the relevant portion of the article below:

> After Visual Studio is installed on a server, the default behavior when an unhandled
>   exception occurs is to show an Exception dialog that requires user intervention to
>   either start Just-In-Time debugging or ignore the exception. This may be undesirable for
>   unattended operation. To configure the server to no longer show a dialog when an
>   unhandled exception occurs (the default behavior prior to installing Visual Studio), use
>   the registry editor to delete the following registry keys:
>
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger`
>
> On a 64-bit operating system also delete the following registry keys:
>
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger`
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger`

Comment: Above did not solve for me on win2012... but I did find a solve (below)

Comment: I needed to disable Windows Error Reporting also.  I recommend this in addition to these steps.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/554596/767098
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 21):

Delete (or rename) c:\windows\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe.

I tried deleting the registry keys, and I tried unchecking all the boxes in the Visual Studio options, but neither worked.

To be clear, my situation wasn't a C++ one.  I was using Micro Focus COBOL for Visual Studio 2010, and by using the registry and VS options suggestions I managed to get rid of the "Want to debug?" dialog, but that resulted in a different dialog to hold up my automated process:

> ### Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
>
> An unhandled exception ('COBOL runtime: Fault detected') occurred in CASDBC.exe [3564]. Just-In-Time debugging
>   this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger
>   has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time
>   debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.
>
> Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for
>   more information.
>
> ### OK

Comment: Finally a solution to this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommend to edit/remove regs. Usually the registry is a mess to play with.

The solution that helps me is a quite simple. I`ve just added JIT debugger to my Visual Studio. Steps are:

- Open `Windows Control panel`
- `Programs`
- `Programs and Features`
- Find `Visual Studio 2017`
- Click `Change`. On a new opened window navigate to the `Individual Components` tab
- Check `Just-In-Time debugger` checkbox
- Click `modify`

[image]

After VS reload the error should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case , on win2012 server, I tried:

- removing registry keys
- deleting the exe for the jit debugger from c:\windows\system32

and it still came up!

I rebooted, etc.
Was making my web site in IIS stall until dialog was acknowledged!

Final solution, which did work: In control panel, in Programs: Uninstalled "Microsoft Visual Studion 2010 Shell (Isolated)"  Uninstalled that, and problem solved.

(Whether SQL Management Studio still works.... I do not know!)

Comment: Worked for me, but be careful. SQL Management Studio will require an install. Also, using IIS Express, ASP errors may no longer be sent to the browser, unless I'm attached to the process, despite scriptErrorSentToBrowser being set to true in applicationhost.config. (Not sure how that happened or what the fix is...)

Comment: SQL Management Studio will indeed stop working if you remove this component. You can fix it, by reinstalling it though.

Answer (score 2):

In the Window for the question

> Do you want to Debug using the selected debugger?

Click *YES* (new window opens) > *OPTIONS* (top row menu) > *DEBUG*

Then in the New window remove the *TICK* which shows *ENABLE JUST IN TIME DEBUGGER*.
After disabling the *JUST IN TIME debugger* close the window or click *OK*
Your problem will be solved. I've tried this and got rid of the *JUST IN TIME POP UP* messages.

Answer (score -2):

Best Solution for this problem is so simple
2 steps to make it done
open cmd prompt
type : regedit
go to path-->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->SOFTWARE-->Microsoft-->Windows NT-->CurrentVersion-->AeDebug
You can find now the file : Debugger 
right click , Modify
copy and paste this text inside it:

drwtsn32 -p %ld -e %ld -g

click ok and voila :)