# Sometimes, but not always, I get a JIT exception on cl.exe if I have a compilation error. How can I disable this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, cl.exe

When compiling C++ in Visual Studio Professional 2022, if there is a compile error, the Just in Time exception popup will appear. This blocks further compilation until the JIT popup is dismissed.

The cause of the exception is unclear. It doesn't seem to be related to any specific file, project, or solution and even specific errors are not consistent. For instance, I had the exception every time I was compiling earlier today. Once I fixed the errors and had a successful compile, I undid my changes just to test and, while I got the same errors, there was no exception.

Has anyone seen this before? Any idea what might be causing it or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I have seen this mostly when I cancel the build. If I understand it correctly, you get it also while you get ordinary compiler errors? In any case, the best thing would be to report a bug.

Comment: How can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Wyck No idea. This happens randomly and isn't even reproduceable in the same session with the same error.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not really possible for me given the way our tools are configured.

Comment: Sounds like hardware problems. Run a memory test, see https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/, and/or google _windows memory test_

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's a pretty specific hardware problem. A memory error that only causes problems when there are real compile errors and which disappears when they're fixed?

Comment: @TheChemist it's just speculation, run the test and you'll see. If the test shows problems, then at least you know the probable cause. I once had a Mac Pro that crashed randomly 2-3 times per day. A memory test showed problems, I changed the RAM and the random crashes went away.

Comment: Well, you can disable the Just-In-Time debugging feature and Windows Error Reporting and just let cl.exe crash normally.  See [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893567/how-to-stop-just-in-time-debugging-messages-blocking-a-buildserver).

Comment: Third-party antivirus products can potentially cause this error. and I suggest you to refer to this [issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-error-message-when-you-run-an-application-that-is-configured-to-be-built-for-the-x64-platform-by-using-the-msvcr90-dll-file-that-calls-the-strncpy-function-an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-application-name-d5632b1b-c1ae-ea18-72f0-fb10d88cedf9).