# Visual Studio 2012: change setting for "Enable floating tab wells"

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm having troubles with VS2012 and code opened in separate windows.

See this screenshot:
[image]

Main windows is open, another window is open (Source Control explorer is just an example for the screenshot, I get the same behavior with source code files). I used to get two items on the task bar for the Visual Studio. Now it is only one.

There is a setting for this:
[image]

But I can't get it undone. Every time I un-check this setting, I get a flicker of another item in task bar, but it goes away immediately. Then I go back to the same settings, the checkbox next to "Floating tab wells always stay on top"  is checked again! That is very annoying.

I have traced the setting to a registry setting `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.Options.TabsAndWindowsOptionsPage\EnableIndependentTabWell` and tried setting it to True (it was False) when VS was not running. But as soon as VS is started, this is switched to False again.

I have installed Power Tools for 2012 - that has some setting for custom tab wells, but I have removed that extension now. I believe the extension caused the issue, but why does it persist after un-installing of the extension? And how do I fix it?

**UPD:** When I run VS in safemode (via `devenv /safemode`) that setting is persisted. But as soon as I run normal mode, it is changed automatically.

**UPD 2:** Resharper 7.1 is to blame. This issue caused by [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-322167). To enable floating tabs going under do the following: this scenarios  require switching the “always on top” option off, you can work around ReSharper behavior by mounting settings file to your ReSharper settings (ReSharper | Manage Options | Add Layer) Please note that this may lead to incorrect behavior of ReSharper functionality in floating windows. Via [Resharper forum](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/resharper-71-early-access-is-open/)

File AllowFloatingTabWells.DotSettings

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Housekeeping/SuppressOwnerlessFloatingWindows/IsDisablingIndependentFloating/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you using  Resharper? Then this might explain the problem. Just search for floating in the following website: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/resharper-71-early-access-is-open/

Comment: Yep, Resharper is the one to blame

Comment: Still persists in 8.1.

Comment: Still persists for 8.2.

Comment: Resharepr 9 and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 6):

Following instructions from a [blog post on the resharper website](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/28/resharper-71-early-access-is-open/), Create a .DotSettings file with this code in it:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Housekeeping/SuppressOwnerlessFloatingWindows/IsDisablingIndependentFloating/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

In visual studio, go to Resharper -> Manage Options -> Add Layer. Find this file and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Window Shortcuts

Below is the list of keyboard shortcuts to control the active window:

- Minimize window  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Maximize/restore window  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Maximize window vertically <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Maximize window horizontally <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- **Toggle “Always on top” <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>**
- Hide window  <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>
- Minimize to tray <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Unhide/Restore from tray <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

Comment: How is that relevant?