# ReSharper 9 broke Visual Studio 2013's "extra code windows", how to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tabs, resharper, resharper-9.0

**Problem:** Visual Studio's "tab wells" or windows are linked/locked in to the primary Visual Studio window and as a result Windows 7 will minimize/show all tab wells and visual studio windows whenever just one of them is clicked. This is very painful when I have code on both of my screens open and then when I try to open up stack overflow on one screen and read that while writing code on my second it will hide the browser in favour of the not-in-use tab well.

**Question Remake:** Alright, so let me start off by saying that this question has already been asked for VS2012 and Resharper version 7.1 here: [Visual Studio 2012: change setting for “Enable floating tab wells”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396596/visual-studio-2012-change-setting-for-enable-floating-tab-wells)

The problem is I'm using Resharper version 9 and the solution (well more work around tbh) in that other question no longer appears to work.

The bug is caused by a problem with Visual Studio and Resharpers way of mitigating it is to lock the tab wells into the primary client, however according to this bug log here: ([RSRP-322167](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-322167)) It appears that the bug is in fact resolved so therefore the work around suggested in the question would be perfect, if only I could get it to work.

Comment: Try installing ReSharper 9.1 EAP 3 https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.1+EAP. Then you will be able to untick "Floating tabs well..." in Tools | Options | Tabs and Windows. Such ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-335147 has been fixed in EAP.

Comment: @Alexander how unstable/buggy would you say the EAP's generally are from Resharper? It's just if this will only be replaced by 1-2 other bugs then it's probably not really even worth going for the EAP. Also, how long do you think it will be until they release a stable path that implements the changes of the EAP's?