# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4: Floating windows focus / Close all documents

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 - I have two monitors attached to my system.

Let's say you drag a couple of windows out to the second monitor so you have a few tabs open there. So something like this:

[image: Visual Studio Two Monitors]

Let's say I then get a Chrome browser window instance open and drag that to my second monitor, so that I see Visual Studio on my left screen and Chrome on my right.

[image: Visual Studio on the Left. Chrome on the Right]

When I then click back into Visual Studio on my left monitor, it hides Chrome and displays the other open tabs on the left Monitor. So I'm back at this, and can't see Chrome any more:

[image: Visual Studio Two Monitors]

It's very frustrating if I want to have a browser open because I'm looking at a solution to a problem and want a reference (or say MSDN open and coding on my main screen). The only solution that I have is to close all my tabs or bring them back to my main window to be working in Visual Studio and have something else on the other monitor.

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 at a previous employment several months ago, and I started my current job about 8 weeks ago. I don't remember this frustrating me at my old job and had the same setup there, so I'm wondering if there's some setting or something different - is there something I can tweak, so that when I have code in the second window, and click code in the primary window?

On an aside, I'm also 99.99% sure that I used to be able to "Close all Windows" by right clicking a tab, and it closed only the code windows in the active set / monitor I was looking at. At the moment, it just goes ahead and closes *everything* on both monitors. As the command says I suppose, but I'm just *positive* I remember different behaviour in the past...

Comment: Ask the boss for a third monitor and put the bowser on that monior :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here, after digging through the settings and googling some of the options:

[Visual Studio 2012: change setting for "Enable floating tab wells"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396596/visual-studio-2012-change-setting-for-enable-floating-tab-wells)

Apparently I'm not going mad and Resharper is to blame (which I didn't have installed in the past)

Follow the answer from `thats_how_i_feel` with the DotSettings file, then you can do tools->options and in the "Tab Well" untick everything.

Aaaaaaah. My environment isn't broken any more!